# How to debug react-scripts run build errno1

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I used create-react-app to create my app, then I used NPM to install some packages that I wanted to use.  When I use npm start run, everything runs fine and I don't have any errors.  However, when I try to use npm run build I get the following error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! runner@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the runner@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-29T21_10_16_413Z-debug.log
```

When I look in the log I can't find anything that would point me in a direction to troubleshoot.  I checked my code, and I don't use any length variable anywhere.  I'm assuming the failure is somewhere else, but I don't even know where to begin looking.  It's weird because it works when I use npm run start.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "runner",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-timeseries-charts": "0.15.5",
    "pondjs": "0.8.10",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The error message seems quite clear: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: I'm not sure that you read the entire post, before attempting to answer.  I do know that is the error, but I'm not using any length property anywhere in the code.  Normally build errors tell you where in the code to look, but in this case it doesn't point me to any of my code.  I was hoping there was a way to find out at least which file was causing the problem.

Comment: Okay. I might have misunderstood your ask. But `length of underfined` means for instance if you use like `name.length`, in this case, `name` doesn't have any value. Did you check that you don't use any `length` method anywhere in your code?

Comment: I'm not using a method like that anywhere in the code, which is why it's so confusing.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the project ?

Comment: I have been having the same exact issue - Could you post the output of your debug log here, which is located in-  C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-29T21_10_16_413Z-debug.log.  That would give more light to this mess.